# JavaScript code in source doesn't reflect code that is actually executed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session-variables

My javascript code appears to work as it's supposed to. However, when I 'view source' in Chrome, it disagrees with the javascript that is actually executed.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['new'] = "blue";
    if (!isset($_SESSION['old'])) { $_SESSION['old'] = "blue"; }
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                changeCol("'.$_SESSION["old"].'","'.$_SESSION["new"].'");
            });
          </script>';
    $_SESSION['old'] = "blue";
?>
```

`$_SESSION['old']="green"` from the previous page. The code is supposed to call `changeCol("green","blue")`, and then set `$_SESSION['old']="blue"`.

In fact, both of these things happen, so my code works as it's designed, **but** if I view source, it says `changeCol("blue","blue")`. This is strange, because if in changeCol() I write the passed variables to `console.log`, I get `green, blue`.

So if it's calling `changeCol(green,blue)` why does it say `changeCol(blue,blue)` when I view source?

Comment: js before php ...its not possible .... php is server side and js is client side

Comment: When you view source, your browser is probably requesting the page a second time, so you get a fresh page with the new session values.

Comment: Did you call session_start()?

Comment: Whatever is wrong is happening server-side. It's not the result of js execution.

Comment: @BrianMarshall ah, good call! I checked developer tools in chrome and it's as you'd expect. if you want to answer i'll give you a check. everyone else: yes. i know php executes first, but that doesn't answer my question. my fault for poor wording.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you view the source, you're probably making an additional request. Your session variable will be reset.

If you're using Chrome or Firefox — which you should be — you can open up either the Web Developer Tools or Firebug and examine the actual DOM tree. (This is also pretty useful in situations where a script has added content dynamically.)

Comment: From my experience, this is most definitely the right answer.

Comment: View source makes a request? In which browsers?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot chrome, apparently!

Comment: Chrome will actually ask you if you want to resubmit the form when you try to view the source.

Comment: @WaleedKhan there is no form, at least not in my example? without a form, it doesn't ask--it just does.

Comment: does appear to be a know issue in chromium http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523

Comment: Someone at Google needs to be fired. View source should not make a new request, at least not without use sanction, otherwise there's a real danger that the source you get is not the source of the page you are viewing. The OP's problem is a case in point, as would be anything with rapidly changing dynamic content, eg news or stock prices sites.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: The current behavior (once you know it) is actually useful for devs to debug pages with changing content. You don't need to refresh the page and view source, refresh and view source, refresh and view source... you can just refresh the source view. Helped me lots of time to spot bits that change in the source just by pressing F5. Note, that chrome implements view source as a protocol, it's `view-source:some_uri` instead of `http://some_url`. So you can go directly to source without rendering the page.

Comment: I concur this is what happens from my experience.

Comment: @slebetman , I can see that F5...F5...F5 might be useful and shouldn't be a problem given that it's under user control. I still demur on View Source making a request on first invocation. That's just plain wrong.

Comment: Besides which, I'm enjoying the 3rd test in Kolkata right now. Cook (162 not out) is going through a bad patch.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include `<?php session_start(); ?>` on your second page?

Comment: If he didn't, it's amazing how well those $_SESSION variables are working. :P

Comment: WIth no session_start, php would make a new array called `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION['old']` would always be unset and set itself to blue. if this were the case